# How can I count the total friends of a Facebook user by uid?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How can I count the total friends of a Facebook user by `uid`?

Answer (score 35):

There is a `friend_count` field against the `user` table that you can query.

```sql
SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

Just replace `me()` with the UID of the user that you want to query.

Answer (score 14):

@Scott

This very much works, I didn't expect it to :)

[https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = 273103345](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20friend_count%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20=%20273103345)

I tried with a random user id who is not a friend in Graph API. However for few random uids it returned null, I am guessing they were pages.

Comment: FQL is deprecated now.

Answer (score 8):

FQL is now deprecated as of October 2014. Quoting Facebook's FAQ :

> As of Tuesday 22nd July 2014, we now return a total_count field within
>   a summary property in the response to /v2.2/me/friends.

The user/friends endpoint does require the user_friends permission to return an actual list of friends who use your app, however the friend count field will still be returned without this the user_friends permission granted. Sample response:

```
    {
  "data": [
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 811
  }
}
```

Full FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#total_friend_count

Answer (score 3):

`COUNT` is not supported by FQL:

```sql
SELECT uid2 
FROM friend 
WHERE uid1 = USERID
```

Since `COUNT` is not supported you need to get all of the records and then count them in whatever application that is making the SQL call.

If you want to get more information, like names, along with count you can use an inner select to get the friend's extended info:

```sql
SELECT name 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 
              FROM friend 
              WHERE uid1 = USERID)
```

Here is a related SO question:

[FQL result count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841569/fql-result-count)

References for [Friend](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend) table:

> Query this table to determine whether
>   two users are linked together as
>   friends.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my solution... works great!

```
$myfriends = $facebook->api('/XXXXXXX152466/friends');
$friendcount =  COUNT($myfriends['data']) + 1;
```

Replace XXXXXXX152466 with the facebook profile id#

Using Facebook PHP SDK along with Graph API!

Comment: I think the result is a paginator, so I should it is not good if an user has a lot of friends.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with `Facebook API 2.0` you [can't get the full list of Facebook friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u), only a partial list of friends that also authorized your app.

You can still get the total number of friends though, the Graph API [user/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/) has a field `summary` containing the count as `total_count`

So you can get it using:

```
FB.api("/me/friends", function (response) {
   if (response && !response.error) {
      console.log(response.summary.total_count);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of way to count the no of friends using Facebook Graph API with Php SDK, out of one i am telling..

```
$fbuser=$fb->api('/me/friends');
$access_token = $fb->getAccessToken();


$friend_count=0;
foreach($fbuser['data'] as $friends)
{
  $friends_count++;
}
```

For complete tutorial visit this article [Getting FB Friends Count](http://www.howtobloger.com/2013/10/how-to-count-all-your-facebook-friends.html)