# Facebook count friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with Facebook API.

I need to get total number of users friends.

```
/me/friends
```

returns only friends that are using app even if I have permission user_friends.

How can I get only number of users friends, nothing more, no need to get their id, mail etc. just total nu,ber of user's friends.

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527518/how-can-i-count-the-total-friends-of-a-facebook-user-by-uid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using API v2.0 you can not get all friends. And if you created your app after 4/30/2014 you have to use API v2.0.

Comment: And if I try with other app that is created before 4/30/2014 it returns only 370-390 friends how to count all even if user has over 1000>

Comment: Is there a next link? How's access token are you using

Comment: $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();$friends  = $facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=5000','GET',['access_token' => $token]);

Comment: And is there a next link in the result?

Comment: How to check that?$facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
     $uid = $facebook->getUser();
  
     if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');$friends  = $facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=5000','GET',['access_token' => $token]);

Comment: Check was $friends is