# Display number of friends using app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to display the number of friends a user has using my app. I've figured out through FQL how to pull out an array of the users friends using the app.

`SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user=1`

Right now, it pulls up an array when displayed. I'm trying to just display the result as a single numerical value. I'm coding in PHP. Anyone know where I need to go from here?

Comment: Assuming you actually don't need the names, just the count, using `SELECT ''` will lower the bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

Select count(*) perhaps.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user=1
```

Comment: Not with FQL -- it's different from SQL. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841569/fql-result-count)

Comment: @rdlowrey Ah, oh well. Just took a guess.

Comment: Be careful ... while I don't do it, there are some SO trolls who love nothing more than to downvote speculative answers that otherwise seem logical :)

Answer (score 0):

`print count($array);` should return the amount of entries in the array